# Robolectric testing in Android Studio Activity Bundle object is null, testing too soon?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, bundle, robolectric

I'm trying to unit test this Android Studio app with Robolectric4.0.1 that has multiple activities in it this particular activity is the login activity but it isn't the first activity launched from `manifest.xml` there are a few activities before it.  Each activity passes a bundle over to the next one.  The problem is that after debugging the `Bundle` object with all of the information I need to test it turns out to be null.

Here is my testing code in the Android test folder:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class LoginActivityTest {
    
    LoginActivity activity;
    

    REdittext email;
    REdittext password;
    TextView signin;

    String e;
    String p;

    Bundle bundle;
    Info info;

    

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        
        activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(LoginActivity.class);



        email = activity.findViewById(R.id.rtxtEmail);
        password = activity.findViewById(R.id.rtxtPassword);
        signin = activity.findViewById(R.id.lblSignIn);
        




        bundle = activity.getIntent().getExtras();


        if (bundle != null) {
            this.info = bundle.getParcelable("Info");
            this.info.bRemember = false;
            this.info.helpWSURL = Common.HELP_WS_URL;

        }


        signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                e = email.getText();
                p = password.getText();


            }
        });
    }






    @Test
    public void test_LoginActivity_ShouldNotBeNull()
    {
        assertNotNull(activity);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_IncomingBundleInfo_NotNull()
    {
        assertNotNull(bundle);

    }
```

This tutorial helped explain on how to do testing in Robolectric section
https://www.sitepoint.com/write-tests-android-development/

So I followed that example but certain objects aren't registering just yet such as `bundle`

My question was when do you actually run the test?  Currently, I'm in Android Studio with that test selected and then the device I want to test on (Samsung SM-T290).  Knowing that this isn't the first activity I'm wondering if `bundle` doesn't even populate with data yet.

Any help would appreciated, thank you.